# Django error when visiting site: syntax error (admin.py, line 4)

Tags: python, django, traceback, django-taggit

I am creating a basic blog with only basic python and the taggit module, it resides at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`   (have to put random spaces in so i can submit)  when i run `./manage.py syncdb` it executes correctly and when i `runserver` it returns no erros. The problem is when i actually visit the website. Than this happens...

```
SyntaxError at /
invalid syntax (admin.py, line 4)
```

This is displayed in the webbrowser..

Here is the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.4.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'taggit',
 'MainBlog')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  298.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  328.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  323.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/Users/zackbaker/MyBlog/MyBlog/urls.py" in <module>
  5. admin.autodiscover()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py" in autodiscover
  29.             import_module('%s.admin' % app)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: SyntaxError at /
Exception Value: invalid syntax (admin.py, line 4)
```

Anyways any help that could be given would be awesome! Thank you guys so much!!

Comment: What is line 4 of `admin.py`?

Comment: @user1074202 What does line 4 of `admin.py` contain?

Comment: from admin.site.register(Post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 4 of your `admin.py` is

```
from admin.site.register(Post)
```

This is a Python syntax error. It should be simply

```
admin.site.register(Post)
```

which calls the appropriate method to register your Post class with Django's admin site.

Incidentally, the `from` keyword in Python is used to import something into your current module. You should make sure you have the line

```
from django.contrib import admin
```

somewhere in lines 1 through 3 of admin.py (probably line 1!), to make sure `admin` is defined correctly by the time you get to line 4.

Comment: Awesome! This worked but now i get a 404 when i visit the page...:( it says                                                                 Using the URLconf defined in MyBlog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.                                     (This is especially strange because when i visit /admin on the page it works fine. hmmmm) any ideas? THanks

Comment: @user1074202 -- What's your URLconf? And what URL are you trying that is giving you the 404? Just the localhost with no additional URL?